# REGEX Adding a string before comma c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I append a known string before each coma on a comma separated string.
Is there a regex for that or something that doesn't use a loop
EX

given string :

```
email, email2, email3  (etc...)
```

to

```
string suffix = "@iou.com"
string desiredResult = "email@iou.com, email2@iou.com, email3@iou.com
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[^,\s]+` regexp, and replace with `"$0"+suffix`:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(original, @"[^,\s]+", "$0"+suffix);
```

`"$0"` refers to the content captured by the regular expression.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/F8WZDf)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
string input = "email, email2, email3";
string suffix = "@iou.com";
//string desiredResult = "email@iou.com, email2@iou.com, email3@iou.com";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace((input + ",")
    .Replace(",", suffix + ","), @",$", ""));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or using LINQ:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",input.Split(',').Select(s => string.Concat(s, suffix))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a zero-length capture group.  Here's how that might look:

```
\w+(?<ReplaceMe>),?
```

The `\w` matches alphanumeric characters, and the named capture group called "ReplaceMe" matches the zero-length space between the end of the word and the beginning of the comma (or any other non-alphanumeric item, including the end of the string).

Then you'd just replace ReplaceMe with the appended value, like this:

```
Regex.Replace(original, @"\w+(?<ReplaceMe>),?", "@email.com");
```

Here's [an example](https://regex101.com/r/eO2lR2/1) ofthat regex in action.